# What is best way to convert a file URL to a BOOST filesystem path in C++?

Tags: c++, filepath, boost-filesystem

I'm writing a library that has filenames as inputs.  One feature that I'm trying to include is to allow the user to pass in file URLs or file paths, because sometimes the input is generated from parsing XML, other time it's not.  I'm using the boost filesystem to manipulate the path, and is wondering what is the best way to convert a file URL to a boost filesystem path object.

Comment: In a platform independent way?

Comment: From what I understand from the the boost filesystem FAQ, they don't support URI, so you would have to manage the URI/URL to something that boost understand.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/faq.htm

M.